# Show JSON Data in Kotlin

Tags: android, json, kotlin

I would like to place JSON Data inside the material card widget (see image). Before asking, I also did my own research - however, I can't seem to fix it. Everything that I try ends up in even more error codes.

For now, I'm just trying to get the right output by using Log. Later on, I want to place the JSON data inside the cards. However, that's a problem for later.

[image: Card Example]

Hopefully providing you with enough information; this is the location of JSON file:

[image: Location JSON-file]

#### Code

```
import getJsonDataFromAsset
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
import kotlinx.serialization.decodeFromString
import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json

@Serializable
data class Item (
    val id: Int? = null,
    val image: String? = null,
    val title: String? = null,
    val description: String? = null,
    val longDescription: String? = null,
    val company: String? = null,
    val price: Int? = null,
    val duration: Int? = null,
    val valued: String? = null
)

    private var json = Json {
        ignoreUnknownKeys = true
    }
      
  val jsonFileString = getJsonDataFromAsset(applicationContext, "activities.json")
        val obj = json.decodeFromString<Item>(jsonFileString.toString())


            if (jsonFileString != null){
                Log.i("data", jsonFileString)
                Log.i("obj.entertainment", obj.description.toString())
            } else {
                Log.e("catch", "Error")
            }
```

#### Beginning of JSON-File.

I want to access the objects/properties inside the items array.

```json
{
    "items" : [
        {
            "id": 0, 
            "image": "img/glowgolf.png",
            "title": "Glowgolf", 
            "description": "Activity description", 
            "longDescription": "Activity description descriptionActivity description descriptionActivity description descriptionActivity description description",
            "company": "Friend", 
            "price": 25, 
            "duration": 2, 
            "valued": ""
        }
...
```

#### Output

```
I/obj.entertainment: null
```

Comment: going to take a wild guess and say you need to change your description `description: String? = null`

Comment: That certainly helped with the error code, however, this is the response;
```I/obj.entertainment: null``` 

I did edit the post, so thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a few more times, the following code showed the desired output.

```
Log.i("obj.entertainment", obj.items[0].title.toString())
```

Output: `Glowgolf`

To place it into your view add `val titleActivityCard = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.titleFirstCard)` and  `titleActivityCard.text = obj.items[0].toString()`

Better answers are always welcome, but hereby the question is closed.